# How to send request with bulk? Elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, request, bulk, request-promise

I have an object with data, and i want to send this data to elasticsearch container

```
      for(let key in params)
               {
                  bulk.push(JSON.stringify({
                index: {
                    _id: params[ key ][ 'id' ],
                    _type: 'id',
                    _index: 'geo'
                }
            }));
            bulk.push(JSON.stringify(params[key]));
        }
        let bulks = bulk.join("\n") + "\n";
```

I made request

```
let cat =  request(
    {
        'method' : 'PUT',
        'uri'    : 'http://dev4.int10h.net:40024/_bulk',
        'body'   : bulks ,
        'json'   : true,
        'headers':
            [
                'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson'
            ],
        'agent'  : false
    }
);
```

but has error

> Unhandled rejection StatusCodeError: 400 - {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\n]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception",**"reason":"The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\n]"},"status":400**}
>       at new StatusCodeError (/usr/lib/node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32:15)
>       at Request.plumbing.callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:104:33)
>       at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/usr/lib/node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
>       at Request.self.callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at Request. (/usr/lib/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at IncomingMessage. (/usr/lib/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1098:12)
>       at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)

How to properly send bulk?

bulks type `string`
[image]

Comment: Please print the result of `let bulks = bulk.join("\n") + "\n";`. How `bulks` looks like?

Comment: @PiotrPradzynski edited

Comment: My guess is that you need `\n\n` in the end. Because `join` does not add `\n` after the last line so with a single `\n` it will look like you have more lines coming after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps you but [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/bulk-index-newline-termination-error-from-elastic-cloud/146247) I found similar problem with `_bulk` and  `JSON.stringify`.

The answer is:

> It looks like the meta characters in your payload does not get
>   translated into newlines. If you instead used the
>   [elasticsearch.js](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/index.html) client, it would handle this for you.

Comment: @Ksym I guess yes. If this is related to newline char encoding you should figure out which would be proper here. Maybe newline from ASCII?